# GridLayout and Spinners under Android

Tags: eclipse, spinner, android-virtual-device, android-gridlayout

I found a bug in Eclipse when developing an Android app : when you have a GridLayout with Spinners inside, and you decide exchanging the position of two spinners, then launch the AVD, the spinners' lists don't change. It surely is a bug and the only solution I found is to `/* */` one Spinner, launch the AVD, uncomment the Spinner and relaunch the AVD. 
It seems to not be a known bug but it's really annoying, if anyone has a solution on how to fix this or a simpler way to revert that bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to make everything go back to normal is edit the id of one problematic spinner in the xml file, and change the call in the class (`R.id.xxxx`), then launch AVD and eventually revert the id and call to what it was before.